# Updating Price List in Excel with vlookup or Index/Match

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm a book wholesaler and need to update my price and stock list constantly to share with some customers in excel format; also to use in importing to websites.

[image: Screenshot of excel]

As in the image above, what I need is a formula for Column D to search for SKU in C2 in  A-column for an exact match; return the value from B to the corresponding cell in D column.

I have searched countless topics, even found a solution in previous weeks but every time I use the same formula I get N/A or REF error.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO. Yor formula is good, but you are mixing numbers with text. In column A, the codes you are listing are stored as TEXT (note that they are left aligned inside cell), but the values you have in column C are stored as NUMBERS (note that they are right aligned insided cell). So Excel is looking for that NUMBER, but it finds no NUMBER in column A that matches, and returns `N/A`.

So before searching, let's convert the number in column C to a text, and let's see what happens. Try something like this:

`=VLOOKUP(TEXT(C2;"@");$A$2:$B$2349;2;FALSE)`

Hope you can adapt this to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the Text/Number difference as I had many of the rows in different format. I've just edited em all to numbers by copying 1 and multipliyng all to get them in proper Number format and Vlookup worked just fine. Thank you again.