# VLOOKUP only returning some results despite all data there [Office 365]

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have recently upgraded to 365 from 2016 and found that when trying to use the same VLOOKUP formula as I have been doing previously, only some values are returned (looks like it is the pure number based ID's are failing to be returned).

I have tried recreating this sheet and recreating the formula (normally a copy and paste from a previous sheet works fine).
Double checked to make sure that the ID's are definitely in the data.

```
=(VLOOKUP(D3,Sheet2!$B$1:E1999,4,FALSE)*E2)
```

[image: Spreadsheet]

This returns N/A, however I have double checked that cell D3's value does exist in Sheet2's array.

[image: Spreadsheet 2]

It should be returning 53.11 but instead shows N/A.
I have checked to make sure that there are no hidden spaces or characters or duplicate entries for this ID.

[image: Spreadsheet 3]

As you can see from this picture, ID's with text in them are returning a result as expected. It's just the numerical ones that are not.

If you have any suggestions, please let me know. 
Thanks!

Comment: D3 is left aligned which indicates text that looks like a number while Sheet2's column B is right aligned indicating true numbers. In VLOOKUP, `1 <> "1"`. Try `=VLOOKUP(N(D3),Sheet2!$B$1:E1999,4,FALSE)*E2`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, unfortunately using that formula hasn't solved the issue.

Comment: Perform `ISTEXT(D3)` and `ISTEXT(SHEET2!B12)` (where B12 is the cell you know exists in sheet2.  You should get the same for both.  Conversly Try `D3=SHEET2!B12` and see if you get a result of TRUE.  If the later is not true, you may have extra spaces or invisible characters in one of the cells.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/53373833/9199828

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get this to working using the IFERROR formula. 
Long winded, but does the job.

```
=IFERROR((VLOOKUP(VALUE(D3),Sheet2!$B$1:E1999,4,FALSE)*E2),VLOOKUP(D3,Sheet2!$B$1:E1999,4,FALSE)*E2)
```

Comment: `=VLOOKUP(IFERROR(VALUE(D3),D3),Sheet2!$B$1:E1999,4,FALSE)*E2` A little shorter for you but slightly different operation.  yours check for an error with the vlookup not finding what you want. and the short version looks for an error converting a text to a number.

Comment: Thanks for that Forward Ed, much simpler!